# How to use decorator after config was injected in flask app?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, decorator

First my project looks like this:

```
├───api
│   ├───config
│   │   └───config.json
│   ├───namespace
│   │   └───routes.py
│   └───auth.py (where the decorator is)
│   │   
│   └───__init__.py (where the config is injected with flask injector)
├───core
    └───example_service.py
```

I have been trying to refactor some existing code on a flask app to avoid having the validation url hardwritten in the code. The idea is to create a decorator @authorize used on every route handler of the app to check if the request header Authorization is set and working.

Right now the decorator looks like this:

```
def authorize(func):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        get_token_info()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

And the validation function looks like this:

```
def get_token_info():
    session = requests.Session()
    res = session.get('my_auth_url', headers={'Authorization' : request.headers['Authorization']}
    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        abort(401)
```

Now, i have an **init** file for my app, where i'm using a flask injector to inject my app's config in my different services classes. The thing is, I would like to also inject the 'my_auth_url' and not write it directly into the code. But it seems flask injector can only inject into classes.

I tried to use the flask global context to make the url accessible everywhere in the app with i figured out that's not it's purpose and I don't really know how to do. (i'm new to python actually)

Thank you very much for your help, and sorry if it's not clear, the project is quite big and it's hard to be clear and concise as the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `my_auth_url` value from your environment variables.

```
def get_token_info():
    my_auth_url = os.getenv('AUTHORIZATION_SERVICE_ENDPOINT')
    session = requests.Session()
    res = session.get(my_auth_url, headers={'Authorization' : request.headers['Authorization']}
    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        abort(401)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I'm using requests cause i need to send a request to my auth service to check if the user token is valid.

Comment: what he is saying is that the flask method will receive a request (OBJECT, not library) that already contains what you are looking for so probably requests (LIBRARY not object) is incorrect

Comment: So, I suggest you to get the 'my_auth_url' value from your environment variables. you can use `os.getenv('KEY', 'DEFAULT_VALUE')`

Comment: now you need to configure the server environment to fulfill this requirement.